# Why Commenting Serial.print() gives me a different value?

Tags: arduino-uno, softwareserial, robotics

I am working on with `Cypress` and `Arduino`.I am trying to transfer the data from `cypress` and printing it to the `Serial Monitor` or Arduino. but the thing is when I am using `Serial.print(j)` it is showing the right value of i (See in the code about what is `i and j`), but when I comment or remove `Serial.print(j)` it is showing the wrong value of `i`
For example, suppose cypress is sending data `00001934a`
and then I am reading this value using

```
int j = mySerial.read()-'0';
// -'0' is for chaging ascii data to normal integer
//for example ascii value of `0` is 48 
//so mySerial will read 48 
// and exprerssion value will become `48-48 = 0`
```

My code

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(10, 11); // RX, TX
void setup() {
Serial.begin(57600);
 while (!Serial) {
; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
}

mySerial.begin(4800);
}

int  i = 0; 
int j = 0;
void loop() { 
if (mySerial.available()) {

        while(j!=49){
        i = i*10 + j;
        j = mySerial.read()-'0';
         //49 is the ascii value of a, I am using this for acting like 
         //a flag, so that i can see the break in data


        Serial.println(j);//commeting this line is causing the problem
      }
   Serial.print(i);
   }
}
```

when the line is not commented the output was

```
0
0
0
0
1
9  
3
4
49
193 //this is the value of i which is correct one
```

but when I comment the line `Serial.println(j)` the output was

```
   14569 // I don't know what the hack is this.
```

Hopefully the problem is understandable, but still, you can comment for more detail.
BTW I am using SoftwareSerial.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. Post a complete, minimal, working sample that show the problem.

Comment: Try now, I have only shown the problem, not all code, but still, it is compilable.

Answer (score 1):

Your serial reading is completely flawed:

```
if (mySerial.available()) {

    while(j!=49){
    i = i*10 + j;
    j = mySerial.read()-'0';
```

What you are saying there is:

- If there is *at least one* character available:
- Read as many characters as can until I get 49.

The main thing wrong with that is that you try and read characters that just don't exist. Serial comes in a byte a time and you *must* wait for those characters to arrive before attempting to read them.  By adding the serial print into your loop you are slowing it down and, by chance, giving the characters time to arrive.

- [Read this to better understand how serial works](https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/01/reading-serial-on-the-arduino/).

Comment: The problem is that the sketch he posted is not the real sketch.

Comment: Please, Wait for some time, I'll post the real code.

Comment: That's a shame. However, if he's (as he probably is) doing the same thing in the "real" sketch (his post belies a fundamental lack of understanding of serial reading) then this is still likely the problem.

Comment: Sir, I know how the read(), function is working, it is reading one char like `0` and printing its ascii value to the serial montior. thats why I am using a flag, so that i an see the break in my data.

Comment: Except if that char hasn't arrived - it returns -1 instead (255 when mapped to an unsigned 8 bit value).

Comment: @Majenko. And why we are here solving elementary programming questions? This question is not really about Arduino.

Comment: I have used `if(mySerial.available()>0){Serial.print("something"); }`to check wheather the data is coming or not

Comment: Yes - if there is one character available then try and read 8. That is wrong. Very very wrong. **Read the blog post I linked to.**

Comment: I should make it more understandable.I think.

Comment: @meditat. It's simple: post the code that outputs the values you show in your question. The last version of your sketch doesn't produce the values you posted. Until that we are just speculating.

Comment: @LookAlterno: According to my test, it does produce the value posted.

Comment: @EdgarBonet. My test output 1
-49
-49
-49
-49
2
-49
-49
-49
3
-49
-49
-49
-49
49
-1239-1239 forever

Comment: Oh look. All those `-49`s. Looks like `-1 - '0'` to me...

Answer (score 1):

Majenko has correctly diagnosed your problem, and the blog post he
linked to is definitely a must-read. The suggested solution, namely
buffering the input until you can read a complete message, is presumably
the most standard way of dealing with an input stream.

It is, however, not the only option. Your idea of building the number
digit by digit can work, if implemented properly, and it can save you
the memory cost of the buffer. The key is to only read bytes when they
are available.

Below is a *non-blocking* implementation of a number reader that works
along the lines of your own code. This function only reads positive
numbers. It returns the number it just parsed upon reading a non-digit
character. In every other case it returns `-1` to tell you there is no
input number available:

```
// Read an positive integer from a stream.
// Returns -1 if a complete integer is not available.
int readInt(Stream &link)
{
    static bool got_a_digit = false;  // did we get a digit so far?
    static int i = 0;                 // the integer we are building
    if (link.available()) {
        char c = link.read();
        if (isdigit(c)) {
            i = 10 * i + (c - '0');
            got_a_digit = true;
        } else if (got_a_digit) {  // non-digit: return the number
            int i_copy = i;
            got_a_digit = false;   // reset for next reading
            i = 0;                 // ditto
            return i_copy;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

And here is how you would use it:

```
void loop() {
    int i = readInt(mySerial);
    if (i != -1)
        Serial.println(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, explain this to me

```
   while(j!=49){
        i = i*10 + j;

        Serial.println(j);//commeting this line is causing the problem
      }
   Serial.print(i);
```

The variable `j` never change inside the `while`.

You print the same `j` time and time again inside the `while`.

The variable `i` keep incrementing inside the `while`. It never stop.

I don't think you posted your real code.

Comment: No `j ` is updating each time using `j = mySerial.read()-'0';`everytime.

Comment: The `while(j!=49)` never end because `j` nevert change **inside** that `while`.

Comment: yup i think so, that should be inside while, let me check and edit.Check now sir.

Comment: Just post your real sketch!